# Blazor File Upload - way too slow

Tags: file-upload, blazor

I created a new Blazor Web Assembly App with Core Hosted, and implemented a file upload as described in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly

The Upload itsself is working, but its unusable slow. I picked a 2 KB File and it took 60 seconds for the request to arrive at the server. With everything larger than like 10 KB I can't even upload it because it reaches a timeout. I set the timeout to 5 minutes and I can't upload a 23 KB png file.

I am using VS 2022 - Version 17.3.3 and created the project today (with NET 6.0), so its completely new and clean.

Even when not debugging, the upload takes the same amount of time. Is there something wrong with my system?

Comment: I now created the same thing on another machine, and there it is working fine. What can I check on my first machine to cause this major delay?

Comment: This is most likely related to the host server settings. Please specify on which server with which operating system you are hosting the application? Try that file access is set on the server.